# CRM 4.0 Access Denied when trying to open an external document from onLoad

Tags: internet-explorer, dom-events, document, onload, dynamics-crm-4

I am trying to open a file when a field is clicked within CRM. I get 'Access is Denied' when the function is called.

```
var FileTextBox = crmForm.all.new_testdoc;
FileTextBox.style.color = "#0000ff";
FileTextBox.style.textDecoration = "underline";
FileTextBox.attachEvent("onclick", openDocument);
function openDocument() 
{ 
if (FileTextBox.DataValue != null) 
{
window.open("FileTextBox");
}
}
```

The data that is contained in the CRM field is 'c:\test\test.txt'

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorted. I needed to make the folder into a shared folder and use that instead eg. \\server\documentpath and prefix it with file:// in the on load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted. I needed to make the folder into a shared folder and use that instead eg. \server\documentpath and prefix it with file:// in the on load.